# nservicebus SetLoggingLibrary

Tags: log4net, nservicebus

I cannot get nservicebus to use a named log4net logger. It seems to only use what is defined in the `<root>` element.

This works fine

```
NServiceBus.SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure);

  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="NServiceBusAppender"/>
  </root>
```

But i really like it to use a named definition.

```
  <logger name="NServiceBusLogger">
    <appender-ref ref="NServiceBusAppender"/>
  </logger>
```

Is this possible?

On their website they are only showing a sample with the `<root>` behaviour.
http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/logging/

Answer (score 1):

All loggers in NServicebus begins with the name "NServiceBus". Have you tried this:

```
<logger name="NServiceBus">
    <appender-ref ref="NServiceBusAppender"/>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need specify the level on the named logger:

```
<logger name="NServiceBusLogger">
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="NServiceBusAppender"/>
</logger>
```

(I assume now that the name of the logger is correct.)

Comment: Forgot it in the example, but that is not the issue.